# How to I advertise my web application?

Tags: advertising, web-services

I would like to know the options I have on advertising my web application ?

Are there websites I can submit my web application to ?

- How important is search engine optimization ? How much effort should I put into it ?
- Currently, my application has two clients, google chrome extension and an emacs client. Are there specific websites/forums I can post these clients to ?
- Any general advice I should follow to advertise my application ?

Little about the application:
It is a note taking application, in which tags are implicitly created from the notes.

If this question should not be posted here, I will delete it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Adwords](http://adwords.google.com/)

Comment: Yep, was thinking into it. Thanks, since I am on a, sort of, short budget. Do you think if I run it for about a month, it would be good enough to start ?

Comment: SEO/Promoting a website is not a time job. It is something that you need to do constantly. In AdWords you can advertise based on your budget, after you got some satisfied customers you can get some customers from "words of mouth" but if depends on too many factors to give you an exact answer. Try it for few weeks using different keywords, try to get some valuable back-links, optimise your titles etc. and wait to see the result(you can use Google Analytics for this monitoring).

Answer (score 1):

> How important is search engine
>   optimization ? How much effort should
>   I put into it ?

Since free traffic is a good thing you definitely should be interested in it. Having said that, you should *need* to put much effort into it. A well built website is search engine optimized by default. Since SEO is mostly a combination of usability, accessibility, semantic markup, and good content a quality website will have kept all of those in consideration while building the site since **that's what users want**. No one in their right mind can reasonably expect to do anything less then that and expect to have a successful website anyway. So if you have to go back and "SEO your website" what you're really saying is you have to go back and "fix your website". If your website was built properly and you have quality content don't worry about SEO. Natural marketing will help you do the rest (e.g. build quality links to your web pages).

Comment: Yep. Free traffic can only be a good thing :) I will look into what is the best website structure for SEO to work well. Thanks.